# Facebook 'pay' method title and description

Tags: facebook, payment

When I user the 'FB.UI' with method pay, like this:

```
var obj =
{
    method: 'pay',
    action: 'purchaseitem',
    product: encodeURI(order_info.product),
    request_id: ....
};

FB.ui(obj, function (data)....
```

How do i change the title & description user see in the payment dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be in your product url, if I understand the question correctly.